# How to extract first digit from a Integer in transformer stage in IBM DataStage?

Tags: datastage

I have an integer field coming and I want to extract the first digit from the field, how can I do it. I cannot cast the field since the data is coming from a dataset, is there a way to extract first digit  from the transformer stage in IBM datastage?

Example:

Input:
`ABC = 1234`

Output: `1`

Can anyone please help me with the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a transformer, define a stage variable as varchar and use this formula to get the substring

```
ABC[1,1]
```

Alternatively you can also convert your numeric value by using the [DecimalToString](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.3.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/r_deeref_Type_Conversion_Functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You CAN convert to string within the context of your expression, and back again if the result needs to be an integer.
AsInteger(Left(ln_jn_ENCNTR_DTL.CCH,1)
This solution has used implicit conversion from integer to string. It assumes that the value of CCH is always an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say- if ABC has type int, you can define a stage variable of type char having length 1.
then you need to convert Number to string first.And use Left function to extract the first char.
Left(DecimalToString(ABC),1).

If you are getting ABC as string, you can directly apply left function.

Answer (score 0):

You can first define a stage variable (name say SV) of varchar type (to convert input integer column into varchar) :
[Stage variable definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9UOr.png)

Now assign the input integer column to stage variable SV and derive output integer column as AsInteger(SV[1,1]) : [Column definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VsQz.png)

i.e. input integer => (Type conversion to varchar) Stage variable => Substring[1,1] and Substring Conversion to Integer using AsInteger.

Answer (score 0):

DecimalToString is an implicit conversion, so all you need is the Left() function. `Left(MyString,1)`